# Small issue with maximum modulus principle proof

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding a fundamental step on a proof of the maximum modulus principle in Hoffman and Marsden's complex analysis text. The authors suppose that $f$ is analytic and has a relative maximum at $z_0$, so $|f(z)|\leq |f(z_0)|$ on some disk centered at $z_0$ with radius $r_0$. They suppose further that there is a point $z_1$ in this disk for which the inequality is strict, that is, $|f(z_1)|<|f(z_0)|$.

Letting $z_1$ equal $z_0 + re^{ia}$ with $r<r_0$, the authors say that due to continuity, we have numbers $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ such that $|f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})|<|f(z_0)|-\delta$ whenever $|\theta - a|<\epsilon$.

This is the part that confuses me in the proof, because I cannot derive this inequality from the definition of continuity. Even writing it in the form $|f(z_0)|-|f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})|>\delta$ does not shed light in this, as it doesn't seem to be a very meaningful inequality and unrelated to the notion of continuity. Can anyone explain to me what is going on in this step? I seem to be missing it.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity implies that for a given $\gamma >0$, $|\, |f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})| - |f(z_1)| \, | < \gamma$ whenever $|\theta - a|<\epsilon$. In particular,
$$
|f(z_0 + re^{i\theta})| < |f(z_1)| + \gamma  = |f(z_0)| - \delta
$$
where $\delta := |f(z_0)| -|f(z_1)| - \gamma$, which is positive for $\gamma$ small enough, since $|f(z_0)| -|f(z_1)|>0$.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple: they consider the continuous function $g(\theta)=\bigl|f(z_0+r\mathrm e^{i\theta}\bigr|$, and they observe that since $g(a)< |f(z_0)|$, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a small neighbourhood of $a$ on which $|g(\theta)-g(a)| < \varepsilon$, so $g(\theta)<g(a)+\varepsilon$. If $\varepsilon$ is such that $ g(a)+\varepsilon<|f(z_0)|$, we can write $g(a)+\varepsilon=|f(z_0)|-\delta$ ($\delta>0$).